# Hive to Hbase comparision of data in tables

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, etl, bigdata

I am into DW testing and need to compare data from source to target.Source data is stored in hive/RDBMS while the target data is loaded in Hbase. I am new to Hbase .Can any one help me with the approach that i can take. What I am looking for is a similar function as that of  "MINUS" . Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

**You should write java file in that you can combine:**

```
HBase:
import java.io.IOException;

// HBASE
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;

import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;



public class RetriveData{

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception{

      // Instantiating Configuration class
      Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();

      // Instantiating HTable class
      HTable table = new HTable(config, "emp");

      // Instantiating Get class
      Get g = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("row1"));

      // Reading the data
      Result result = table.get(g);

      // Reading values from Result class object
      byte [] value = result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("personal"),Bytes.toBytes("name"));

      byte [] value1 = result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("personal"),Bytes.toBytes("city"));

      // Printing the values
      String name = Bytes.toString(value);
      String city = Bytes.toString(value1);

**// CALL THE HIVE CLASS(HiveQLOrderBy)...YOU CAN COMPARE**

      System.out.println("name: " + name + " city: " + city);
   }
}


//HIVE

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class HiveQLOrderBy {
   private static String driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

   public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

      // Register driver and create driver instance
      Class.forName(driverName);

      // get connection
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/userdb", "", "");

      // create statement 
      Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

      // execute statement
      Resultset res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY DEPT;");
      System.out.println(" ID \t Name \t Salary \t Designation \t Dept ");

      while (res.next()) {
         System.out.println(res.getInt(1) + " " + res.getString(2) + " " + res.getDouble(3) + " " + res.getString(4) + " " + res.getString(5));
      }

      con.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @R Palanivel , but what i understand from the Java File above is that it will separately print the result from Hbase table and Hive then will have to manually compare it. Please correct me if I am wrong. I have not been able to implement it as of now. Please suggest.